# Using SQL Profiler on SSIS package

Tags: ssis, profiler

Is it possible to use SQL Server Profiler to trace a running SSIS package? I tried to do that, but all I can see in the trace is executing dp_sqlagent_... and the other internal commands! None of the tables/script that the package is working on displayed in the trace.

I tested different trace templates but had not much lock. Have you got any experience in this area?

Thank you.

Cheers,
Nazila

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you aren't seeing the activity in your trace, it may not be getting that far. You'll want to turn up some [logging for your SSIS package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138020%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: For any other person benefit, as Eric mentioned above, to be able to trace a SSIS package in SQL Server Profiler, you need to first set the SSIS loggings int the package. Follow the steps below: Open the SSIS solution > Clik on SSIS menu > Add a new log while you choose the Provider Type  as 'SSIS log Provider for Windows Event log' > Click on Details tab and select any events you are interested in logging > Save the log entry.

Answer (score 1):

BIDS Helper has a built-in package profiling tool which is pretty cool when running the package interactively.  It's available (once you've installed BIDS Helper) by right-clicking the package and then 'Execute and Visualize Performance'.

[bidshelper.codeplex.com](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/)